# diff command indicates files differ but they don't

Tags: python, file, compression, diff, bin

I created a LZ compressor and I'm checking if it's working by compressing a file_a into a file.lz and decompressing it back to file_b and then comparing file_a and file_b. When i use diff it says the files differ and cmp says file.bin file2.bin differ: char 1, line 1.
I think the compressor code is OK and when i read both files like this:

```
with open("file.bin", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

i = int.from_bytes(data, "big")

input_str = bin(i)[2:]

with open("file2.bin", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

i = int.from_bytes(data, "big")

input_str2 = bin(i)[2:]

if(input_str==input_str2):
    print('equal')
else:
    print('diff')
```

it always prints equal.

Comment: `input_str = bin(i)[2:]` You're skipping the first two items.  What happens if the files are the same, _except_ for those first two items you skipped?

Comment: Use `cmp -b` to show the actual differences.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's the same, i just remove the 0b from both.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried that and i get this ```file.bin file2.bin differ: byte 1, line 1 is 337 ?   0 ^@```. Not sure what this means.

Comment: `file.bin` starts with a BOM character. 337 is the first byte of BOM.

Comment: The compressor should open the file in binary mode. In text mode it use BOM to tell it the encoding of the rest of the file, and it's not saved in the output.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the input. Can you please tell me what I should change then? Currently I'm reading the file like this in the compressor:                        `with open(input_file, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()

    i = int.from_bytes(data, "big")

    input_str = bin(i)[2:]`

Comment: So you're using `bin(i)[2:]` to skip over the BOM character? Why? The problem is that the decompressor doesn't add it back.

Comment: Now I know that is the BOM character. Basically when I printed input_str I would get something like`b'01010101` and i did that to remove the b'. Maybe I should try adding it when writing file2.bin?

Comment: I see. So you write your own compression and decompression code, test it with diff and cmp, those both claim that the output differs from the input, and your conclusion is that diff and cmp must be wrong?!

Comment: Well if you suggest a better title, I can change it. However I think the problem becomes clear if you read the post. The compression is working fine in all the bytes except the first due to what i assume from the comments above, a BOM character which i do not need to compress for the project that I'm working on.@MarkAdler